# Modern News Post with scheduling: how to filter with KQL the Publish Start Date

Tags: highlighted-content-web-part, schedule, news-webpart

When scheduling is activated the column with the future date is called Publish Start Date. What is the real name of this column?

I tried several experiments involving several names and >Today but it does not work.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you check if this name `PublishingStartDate` works?

Comment: But if you are using Scheduling date then I guess you don't need to query specially for that because internally SharePoint will publish that news automatically on given dates only and then only it will be visible to end users

Comment: I checked PublishingStartDate but I cannot manage it to work. I need that 1 person is able to see all the scheduled items with publication date in the future so I need a way to query to list all the scheduled news in the hub

Comment: PublishingStartDate>Today, this is the syntax I have used. With variations on the parameter's name